# UIView.animateWithDuration: animation always stops at original position

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

I added an `ImageView` in the middle of my view (no constraints set).

With this code I want to move this `ImageView` from its original position to a new one.

Unfortunately, it moves from the new to its original position - why?

```
let opts = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: opts, animations: {
     self.ivSun.center.x += 100
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Do you mean it goes back to the original point when animation is done or does it skip to x + 100 and then animates back to original point?

Comment: How often do you use this animation? do you repeat it often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after completion of your animation.

```
self.ivSun.layer.position = self.ivSun.layer.presentationLayer().position
```

I have code that implemented in my game.

```
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
                    self.viewBall.layer.position = self.viewBall.layer.presentationLayer().position
            }
        }
        var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = ballMoveTime
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: viewBall.layer.presentationLayer().position)
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.borderRight, self.borderMiddle))
        animation.removedOnCompletion = false
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        viewBall.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "transform")
        CATransaction.commit()
```

Change position value as you need.

Comment: where you have wrote? can you show complete code plz.

Comment: This works fine! Thanks a lot. But why is it so difficult to move a view?

Comment: You also can do this via UIView animation but you told me this is not done so i have given this code. bcoz this is nothing but i have to see your full code so i can tell what is the prob. with this animation(it takes time to so.). and alos one thing you can achieve this with removing some lines of code like you can remove CATRransaction from the code and just with CABasicAnimation. :-)

Comment: This seems overkill. He should probably solve the underlying problem of why the UIView animation doesn't work instead. Like, are you using constraints to layout your view? If so, then you have to update the constraints and ask the view to update the layout in the animation block. @AntonSack if you're using constraints, I will add the code to animate easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
func animateImage()
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.imageView.center.x+10, self.imageView.center.y+10)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the context and related code it's difficult to give an answer on "why" it's snapping back to its original position, but as an alternative you could set the completion handler with whatever you'd like as the final position/coordinate.

Generally I use constraints on my widgets/views, and I animate their values (versus animating the widgets' frame, for example) ... with excellent results.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to autolayout. Constraints need to be changed and updated in the the animation as seen below:

```
- (IBAction)moveAction:(id)sender {
    self.spaceConstraint.constant += 220;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
         [self.imageView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.duration = ballMoveTime
animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: viewBall.layer.presentationLayer().position)
animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.borderRight, self.borderMiddle))
animation.removedOnCompletion = false
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
viewBall.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "transform")
CATransaction.commit()
```